Consumir webservices SOAP en Google Apps Script
Tengo una consulta para ver si alguien ya ha podido, necesito consumir un webservices SOAP en Google Apps Script sin embargo he intentado y no me ha funcionado
seria este el de la imagen:

El codigo que ejecuto para consumirlo es este:
function consumirWebService(pvcDocumentosXML,pvcCorreoUsuario,pvcClaveUsuario) {
  var url = 'https://pruebas.gticr.com/AplicacionFEPruebas/WSCargaFactura/Pruebas/GTICargaFactura.asmx?op=InsertarDocumentos';
  var soapRequest = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
    'method': 'post',
    'contentType': 'text/xml',
    'payload': '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">\n' +
      '   <soapenv:Body>\n' 
 +
      '      <InsertarDocumentos>\n' +
      '         \n' +
      '         <pvcDocumentosXML>' + pvcDocumentosXML + '</pvcDocumentosXML>\n' +
      '         <pvcCorreoUsuario>' + pvcCorreoUsuario + '</pvcCorreoUsuario>\n' +
      '         <pvcClaveUsuario>' + pvcClaveUsuario + '</pvcClaveUsuario>\n' +
      '      </InsertarDocumentos>\n' +
      '   </soapenv:Body>\n' +
      '</soapenv:Envelope>',
      muteHttpExceptions:true
  });

  var soapResponse = soapRequest.getContentText();
  Logger.log(soapRequest);
  //Logger.log(soapResponse);
}

Sin embargo no me funciona lo probé en ambientes que si ya he realizado consumos de este tipo y si me funciona como en C# por ejemplo, pero en Google Apps Script no me funciona , quería saber si alguien ya ha pasado por un problema similar y ha encontrado una solución, de ante mano, muchas gracias!

Hola. Activa el Logger.log(soapResponse) y dinos  qué muestra exactamente.

Hola, muestra este mensaje : Información '''



Error al procesar el request


Error al procesar el request, por favor valide los datos enviados, si el problema persiste contacte al administrador de sistema.

''' Sin embargo lo probé en otra plataforma utilizando C# los mismos datos y si funciono  es esa especificamente apps script de google que me da problemas
Pulsa en [edit] para agregar en la pregunta cualquier información aclaratoria.

El mensaje indica que el Web Service no está devolviendo una respuesta válida. Antes de intentar leer una eventual respuesta debes hacerlo funcionar en ese entorno,  precisamente por eso lo primero es verificar que la respuesta es correcta
